# Using Renderer2 to add template variable in dynamically created `div`

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to achieve this:

```
<div #component></div>
```

with this:

```
const el = this.renderer2.createElement('div');
el.setAttribute('#component')
```

Can I do this? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but if it is for dynamic components, [here you go](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Otherwise if you want to find an HTML element, simply use `document.querySelector`. You can't add template variables post-build, as they need to be compiled.